# Proving, that $\text{Arg}(-i\sin(x))=\pi/2\text{sgn}(x)$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Alright. I thought, that $\text{Arg}(-i\sin(x))=3\pi/2$, however, [the Wolfram Alpha tells a different story](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arg(sin(x))). I am sure that it must be kind of true, because $\text{Arg}(\sin(x))$ is the result of sum of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sin((2n+1)x)}{2n+1}$, which is a fourier series of the sign function. But I have a little problem proving this fact.

Comment: What's your $x$? Real? Complex?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Comment: @Vim: Would $\text{sgn } x$ make sense for non-real $x$?

Comment: I don't know. But since what you want to know I the first place is $\sin$ instead of $\text {sgn}$ so I think it makes no difference.

Comment: The problem resides in the range of $\arg$: do you take it to be $[-\pi, \pi)$, or $[0, 2\pi)$, or something else? Also, $\arg (- \textrm i \ \sin x)$ must depend on the sign of $x$, so it cannot be $\frac {3 \pi} 2$ as you write. Finally, your input to Wolfram Alpha does not contain $- \textrm i$. Quite many mistakes in such a short question.

Comment: Come on, @Vim, let's stop playing: the OP uses a Fourier series for $\arg \sin x$ - have you ever seen Fourier series for a complex variable? The whole post indicates a real variable.

Comment: @AlexM. I know little about Fourier :)  I suppose it is too trivial for real $x$, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments there are some mistakes in the question, and I don't understand what the Fourier series have to do with the problem.

Anyway, we  have:
$$
-\pi<x<0 \Rightarrow \sin x<0 \Rightarrow -i\sin x =i |\sin x| \Rightarrow \mbox{arg}(i |\sin x|)=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
$$
x=0 \Rightarrow \sin x=0 \Rightarrow -i\sin x =0 \Rightarrow \mbox{arg}(-i \sin x)=0
$$
$$
0<x<\pi \Rightarrow \sin x>0 \Rightarrow -i\sin x =-i |\sin x| \Rightarrow \mbox{arg}(-i |\sin x|)=-\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

so the correct result is:
$
 \mbox{arg}(-i \sin x)=-\frac{\pi}{2}\mbox{sgn}(x)
$ for $-\pi <x<\pi$.

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin((2n+1)x)}{2n+1}=\lim_{r\to1+}\Im\int\sum e^{ix}r^ne^{i2nx}dx=\lim_{r\to1+}\Im\int\frac{e^{ix}}{1-re^{2ix}}dx=\Im( i\frac{1}{2}(\ln(1-e^{ix})-\ln(1+e^{ix})) ) =Arg\frac{1-e^{ix}}{1+e^{ix}}=Arg(\frac{-i\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)})=Arg(-i\sin(x))$
and simultaneously
$K\text{sgn}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin((2n+1)x)}{2n+1}$ set the constant $K$ accordingly so that the equality holds. Don't have the time to check it.

Answer (score 1):

This is true $\text{Arg}(-i\sin(x))=\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot \text{sgn}(x)$,  $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$

Recall that the principal argument $\text{Arg}(z)$ lies in the domain $-\pi<\text{Arg}(z)\le \pi$. 
Setting $y=\sin x$, then $y \in [-1,1]$. Note that  $z=-iy$  is a pure imaginary complex  number, and the sign of the imaginary part is $\pm$ (liying on the $y$-axis) depends on the sign of the number $y$. Thus,   $\text{Arg}(-iy)=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}\text{sgn}(x)$.